# MySQL JSON_TABLE to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, json, postgresql

I am new to Postgres and just migrated all DBs from MySQL to Postgres 12. So I am currently modifying all of the MySQL.connectors code in the Python files from MySQL to Postgres. One of the Python files has this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT m.invoice_no, SUM(n.amount) AS patient_payable 
FROM ex_invoice m, JSON_TABLE(m.payment, '$[*]' COLUMNS(amount DOUBLE PATH '$.amount')) AS n 
GROUP BY m.invoice_no;
```

The output by MySQL:

```
invoice_no                          patient_payable
10008714b3dcc2486614275921d94db0    356.81
1000cdd124e28dae5829252384ecf792    0
1000fe2953204ccd49abaa6fd8053db2    235.4
100112a4bd354870d80f6e0177283a43    183.55
10012b1c2f8f36537bc5dc405a877116    114
1001966dcaf420ca0d3cd9f49e072bfa    149.8
1001f7bf52de5c8cfdfc1fab530d59cb    507
10025043f3e6a4a11525da9bae831f1c    456
1002f26f72ba1a8692abf929c1ab4825    221
1003ef6020adbefc3372c719d8abccca    150.68
```

The JSON format in the **payment column** looks like this:

```
  "[
    {
        ""_id"": ""088447"",
        ""ref"": """",
        ""corp"": """",
        ""void"": 0,
        ""amount"": 260,
        ""void_by"": """",
        ""void_on"": ""0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000"",
        ""location"": ""Queenstown"",
        ""invoice_id"": ""jNVJ6e131R310M4vG6cxiI526O8m4Fzu"",
        ""void_reason"": """"
    }
  ]"
```

I want it to be interpreted in Postgres but Postgres 12 doesn't have the **JSON_TABLE()** and **COLUMNS()** that extract the values from the JSON format. I have been searching for days and tried many possible solutions but couldn't succeed, please help.

Comment: If you have been searching for days, you cannot have searched very thoroughly, since the PostgreSQL documentation describes pretty clearly how to extract an attribute from a JSON.

Comment: What about any of these functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

Comment: You can use json_table later this year. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONTABLE)

Comment: also better use numeric for `amount` column.

Comment: "just migrated all DBs from MySQL to Postgres 12" and then seeing this? Did you do ANY research before you  started this migration? and why the choice for [12](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) and not for 13 or 14  ?

Comment: Because the developer’s site is using Postgres 12, our backend team just follow them.

Comment: Hi Frank, I read and tried, the outputs were all Null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most probably looking for `jsonb_array_elements()`

```
SELECT m.invoice_no, 
       SUM((n.element ->> 'amount')::double precision) AS patient_payable 
FROM ex_invoice m
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(m.payment) as n(element) 
GROUP BY m.invoice_no;
```

This assumes that `ex_invoice.payment` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to use `json_array_elements()` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @a_horse_with_no_name, the json_array_elements() works like a charm! 
The jsonb_array_elements() will ask to specify the type casts.

Comment: @iBoon: the recommended data type to store JSON values is `jsonb` - you should consider changing the column's data type in the long run.

Comment: I have a similar MySQL query but with an additional column:
`SELECT m.invoice_no, GROUP_CONCAT(n.corp ORDER BY n.corp ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS co_payer,
SUM(n.amount) AS co_payer_payable 
FROM ex_invoice m, JSON_TABLE(m.corporate, '$[*]' COLUMNS(corp VARCHAR(125) PATH '$.corp', amount DOUBLE PATH '$.amount')) AS n
GROUP BY m.invoice_no;`

Comment: Here's my code for Postgres:
`SELECT m.invoice_no, STRING_AGG((n.element ->> 'corp')::VARCHAR, ', ' ORDER BY n.element) AS co_payer,
SUM((n.element ->> 'amount')::DOUBLE PRECISION) AS co_payer_payable 
FROM ex_invoice m
CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(m.corporate) AS n(element)
GROUP BY m.invoice_no;`

However, it returns an error "ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type json".
If I remove `ORDER BY n.element`, it returns another error "ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar". 

What's wrong with my code?